# Error while adding NuGet Package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am getting the following exception while adding NuGet package to project. I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 Pro.

[image]

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT It is still occurring here is the list of the output
https://www.dropbox.com/s/acaxkhqtrspqd5h/output.txt?dl=0

Comment: There are no packages been read locally I can delete package folder all packages will be deleted from the nuget.org.

Answer (score 0):

try going to  VS settings -> NuGet settings -> clear the NuGet cache, close Visual Studio, and delete all obj and bin folders in solutions .

Comment: Tried but then also when adding the package again it giving same error.

Comment: you have 32 update , did u tried updating some importants other nuget packages , such as xamarin.forms and related to google nuget packages

Comment: try uninstalling **all** NuGet packages and after that install the plugin that show error in this example GooglePlayServices.ads.lite **first** and after that install others plugin

Answer (score 0):

> Error while adding NuGet Package

AFAIK, It seems an issue which needs to be fixed from Xamarin team and someone already reported it:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61113

You can track this thread to get future updates for this issue.

Here are some of the workarounds already mentioned in that thread:

- **Update the packages with the option `-IgnoreDependencies` in the Package Manager Console** (It works for me):

  ```
  Update-Package -IgnoreDependencies
  ```
- Update Visual Studio to latest version and running as Administrator
- Some of the files in the packages folder were set to read-only. Try to cleare the read-only flag from all files in the packages folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did not work for me still not able to add NuGet package to the project.

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot of ways to solve this problem. But unfortunately cleaning the cache, project, rebuilding didn't help. The only thing I didn't try is to re-install Visual Studio or Windows.
I've got to launch project in Visual Studio for Mac and update/add all the necessary Nuget packages from there. On the Mac, the process was successful. I know this might not be an option if you don't have device, but it definitely works.